# Smartest way of having a subscription but multiple users subscribe to it [STRIPE]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments

I have a monthly subscription and the amount are only $5 - $50, ($5 intervals).

One user chooses a plan for their account and another user can buy that persons plan. Problem comes with, lets say I want to call if user A is subscribed to User B. I can't call a `$user->subscribed('plan5')` because what if other users are subscribed to the same plan?

How can I go around this? Would I need to create a new plan for each user? And then subscribe them to that plan?

Comment: Why don't you just rpefix every plan with the key of the user ID? ie. '342_plan5'

Comment: @Layke Plan gets created either on stripe or via api. Therefore even doing that will mean I'll need unique plans, I thought there was a way around this. My plan of a general approach will not work for this. Thank you though.